# Enable MathJax in elasticearch result with Ajax call

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, mathjax

I use [mathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) in blog post and everything works fine when the post is viewed. But in [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) search result with ajax I get `x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}` instead of

[image]

I reload `MathJax` after `Elasticsearch` ajax call is fired, Like this:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML",
      dataType: "script",
 });
```

But unforunetly it doesn't work.

How can I fix this problem?

**UPDATE:**

```
function ajaxSeach(term) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Search/AjaxSearch?term=' + term,
        error: function () {
        },
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {    
            var newElement = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
                newElement += '<div>';
                newElement += '<a href="/Posts/Post/' + data.result.[i].id + '/' + '>' + data.result[i].title + '</a>';
                newElement += "</div></hr>";
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML",
                dataType: "script",
            });
            $('#ajaxSearchContainer').html(newElement);                
        },
        type: 'GET'
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show the piece of code where you retrieve the formula from Elasticsearch and how you display it on screen?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading MathJax.js multiple times will have no effect (it detects itself running).

You need to tell MathJax to typeset the newly arrived content. [From the MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html):

> To queue the typeset action, use the command
>
> ```
> MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
> ```

Add this to `success` and you should see MathJax render the new content.